# Multithreading in java some query regarding execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose we have class

```
class Temp{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Temp().method1();
    }

void method1(){
// if this method is not using any global variable will call to this is thread safe

method2()

}

void method2(){
// if method1 declared as synchronized then execution in method2 will be thread safe ot there might possibility of clashig the threads inside this
}

}
```

if we create multiple thread to call method1 what would happen in above case. I am bit confused.

Comment: may I suggest you take a look at the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and even better at Brian Goetz's [Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1399382392&sr=8-1&keywords=java+concurrency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them should be thread safe.

Basically your method is thread safe

1. Method does not refer any class level variable. as thread will have local copies for local variables.
2. Or defined as synchronized

Try to achieve 1st strategy for thread safety if possible

Comment: Could you explain *why* this is the case?

Comment: this is not really an exhaustive list: immutable and stateless objects are thread safe as well. Moreover, synchronization alone does not guarantee thread safety because deadlocks can still happen. Thread safety is achieved through careful design.